# How can I cut down this StringBuilder function?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, stringbuilder

I have a function in a Visual Basic .net program which takes several parameters, and appends them together to form a string. The result is a valid SQL command which is returned to the main program.

Code in question:

```
Private Function StringBuilderCommand(Field, Table, CurrentCellValue, SearchParameter)
    'Creates a suitable SQL string.
    Dim MyStringBuilder As New StringBuilder("SELECT ")
    MyStringBuilder.Append(Field) ' Append the parameter 'Field'.
    MyStringBuilder.Append(" FROM ") ' Append the SQL command 'FROM'.
    MyStringBuilder.Append(Table) ' Append the parameter 'Table'.
    MyStringBuilder.Append(" WHERE ") ' Append the SQL command 'WHERE'.
    MyStringBuilder.Append(SearchParameter) ' Append the parameter 'SearchParameter'.
    MyStringBuilder.Append("=""")
    MyStringBuilder.Append(CurrentCellValue) ' Append the parameter 'CurrentCellValue', representing the cell selected.
    MyStringBuilder.Append("""") 'Append a quotation mark.

    Return MyStringBuilder.ToString() ' Return it to the main program.
```

However, I feel that this code is too messy. How could I go about making it more efficient or at least, cleaner to look at?

Comment: Remove that function from your code and learn how to build parameterized queries. The commands you build with that function will be open to sql injection and cannot work with non string data types (and also with strings you could have many problems if there is a double quote in CurrentCellValue)

Comment: You could remove the useless comments.  a = 1 ' Set the variable a to 1

Comment: @user7378 Please don't forget to accept the best answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any reason you don't use string.format? So something like this:

```
String.Format("SELECT {0}  FROM {1} WHERE {2} = {3}", _
              field, table, searchparameter, currentcellvalue)
```

See [String.Format() documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) for more information.

edit: As Jon Skeet has pointed out below, constructing your SQL in this way is a bad idea, leaving you vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Please see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection for more information including details on mitigation.

Comment: No mention of the SQL injection vulnerability? This is just *not* something you should be doing...

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I've updated my answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

this is at least less typing and clutter:

```
    'Creates a suitable SQL string.
    Dim MyStringBuilder As New StringBuilder("SELECT ")
    With MyStringBuilder
        .Append(Field)    ' Append the parameter 'Field'.
        .Append(" FROM ") ' Append the SQL command 'FROM'.
        .Append(Table)    ' Append the parameter 'Table'.
        .Append(" WHERE ") ' Append the SQL command 'WHERE'.
        .Append(SearchParameter) ' Append the parameter 'SearchParameter'.
        .Append("=""")
        .Append(CurrentCellValue) ' Append the parameter 'CurrentCellValue'
        .Append("""")    'Append a quotation mark.
    End With
    Return MyStringBuilder.ToString() ' Return it to the main program.
```

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner version of the above code along with protection from sql-injection attack:

```
Private Function StringBuilderCommand(Field, Table, CurrentCellValue, SearchParameter) 'Creates a suitable SQL string.
    Dim MySqlCommand As New SqlCommand()
    Dim MyStringBuilder As New StringBuilder("")
    MyStringBuilder.Append("SELECT @Field FROM @Table WHERE @SearchParameter = @CurrentCellValue")

    MySqlCommand.CommandText = MyStringBuilder.ToString()
    MySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Field", Field)
    MySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Table", Table)
    MySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@SearchParameter", SearchParameter)
    MySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@CurrentCellValue", CurrentCellValue)

    Return MySqlCommand
```

I have returned SqlCommand object in order to avoid sql-injection attack.